# Generate ID based on intersecting points

Tags: qgis, expression

I am new to QGIS and have a bunch of points that require an endpoint id. this endpoint id needs to be the name of another point layer that they are snapped to.

Is there any easy way of getting the field calculator to update my endpoint id based on the name field within the points they intersect with.

So for example:

Point A requires the endpoint id field to be the name field of point B. I wish to pull out the name field from point B and set it as the name field in point A.

*I realise my description is a little janky but I can try clarify anything if it helps.*

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```sql
aggregate(
layer:='PointB', -- layername you want to get the attribute from
aggregate:='array_agg', -- method of aggregation.. you could also use 'concatenate'
expression:="id", -- fieldname you want to get the attribute from
filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)) -- filter: only get the ones that intersect
)[0] -- the function returns an array. [0] will get the first element of this array
```

Alternatively you could also use `array_to_string()` instead of `[0]` to get all values concatenated by a separator. Since QGIS 3.16 you can also use `overlay_intersects()` function instead of `aggregate()`. Also, since 3.16 you could use `overlay_nearest()` in case the points do not 100% overlay each other but are close.

Comment: i did attempt to use overlay intersects as ive used overlay within for a similar issue with generating ids based on the poly they were in but had no luck due to me not really understanding what im doing.  

so if im right :
aggregate(layer:='point B',aggregate:='array_agg',expression:="name",filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry))[0]  

will that make the name now my endpoint id ?

Comment: apologies for the lateness in my reply. I got kicked out the office and then the weekend happened. so I have tried putting the expression you gave me into the field calculator but it only returns NULL. Picture 1 is the layer with the endpoint ID i need to set with the name field of pictures 2 and 3 depending on which layer A intersects (it will be either a chamber or a pole) there is roughly 180 items in layer A if this matters at all Pic 1: https://imgur.com/vOf8Ai3 Pic 2: https://imgur.com/nhHNE4r Pic 3 : https://imgur.com/gwTqJkV

Comment: I will also need a similar thing in the future to create a list of points that a line intersects with i assume this is also achieveable with a similar overlay_intersects command

Comment: If you use the expression from your first comment, you are referencing the wrong layer and also you are using the wrong filter. Adjust your layername and use `filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))` as filter. If it still returns null, it might be the case that your points do not actually intersect, but are just very close. If that is the case, you can use overlay_nearest() since QGIS 3.16.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution to this problem using the vector overlay process.

By selecting all the fields except the one I wanted to populate in Layer A and only the field I wanted to use to populate the endpoint id Field in Layer B this then generated a new layer containing all the information I required.

All that was left then was to rename the new name_2 field as endpoint_id and save the temporary layer